# Order objects by date of creation ( one day)

Tags: objective-c

Hi have a class like this:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
property(nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *dateCreated;
@end
```

and i have an array of objects of type Foo created like this :

```
NSMUtableArray *array = [NSMUtableArray array];
Foo *foo1 = [Foo alloc] init];
foo1.dateCreated =[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[NSDate timeIntervalSince1970]]; 
[array addObject:foo1];

Foo *foo2 = [Foo alloc] init];
foo1.dateCreated =[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[NSDate timeIntervalSince1970]]; 
[array addObject:foo2];

....
```

The objects foo1,foo2,... are not created at the same time. The are created in différents dates.

Question :

I would like to order my objects by day , i mean by this have all the objects for created for example : 06 Sep 2009, and an other list created the 07 Sep 2009,....

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Why are you storing the time interval number instead of the date? And do you mean 'order' (sort) or do you mean 'group' (it sounds like you mean group)?

Comment: Because i am using coreData ;). Yes i mean group my objects by day.

Comment: Core Data is fully capable of storing dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the first creation date of all of your objects. It is the first day used to begin your iteration. Find the last creation date, this tells you when the iteration is complete. Both of these dates need to be converted so they are at the start and end of the day (respectively).

Iterate, starting at the first date and continuing until the last date, adding a day worth of seconds each time.

Note that this same process will work with stored dates instead of numbers, but you'd use `NSDateComponents` and it would deal easier to calculate the first and last dates and to add the day time interval.

During your loop you have 2 dates:

1. The start date of that iteration
2. The end date of that iteration (1 second less than a full day added to the start date)

With this information you can run a predicate on your list of source objects:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dateCreated >= %@ AND dateCreated <= %@", startDate, endDate]
```

Check if there is anything in the resulting array after the filter (`filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`) and, if there is a result, add it to your result list (or dictionary).